# How to display jQuery/Javascript functions to <pre> (string)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I wonder how to covert jQuery or Javascript functions to string and display into some element like a `<pre>`

**HTML :**

```
<pre></pre>
```

**jQuery :**

```
function test() {
    alert('test');
}

$('pre').html(test()); // <-- I have no idea
```

**Playground :** http://jsfiddle.net/p8Q5p/

**So HTML will be..**

```
<pre>alert('test');</pre>
```

Possible ?

Comment: Use `$('pre').html(test.toString())` as a starting point. Mind that browsers will format this string differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$('pre').html(test.toString());
```

but you will need to remove surounding `function test() {` you can use regex for this:

```
$('pre').html(test.toString().replace(/function [^(]+\([^)]*\) *{.*}/, ''));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `toString()` method:

```
$('pre').html(test.toString());
```

In your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p8Q5p/4/

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
function test() {
    alert('test');
}
var functionString = test.toString();
$('pre').html( functionString);
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/p8Q5p/3/)